# ¿Como ubicar el foco de una DataGridView en el ultimo registro ingresado en C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Buenas ahora tengo esta duda y no encuentro lo que busco, ocupo que la `DataGridView` al momento de ingresar un nuevo registro este marque, seleccione, muestre, enfoque o como quieran llamarle a esa accion a ese nuevo registro ya que ocupa muchos registro y solo se queda enfocado en la primer celda. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > ¿Como ubicar el foco de una DataGridView en el ultimo registro ingresado en C#?

Debes hacer uso de la propiedad [CurrentCell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell?view=netframework-4.8) para lograr que la última celda de la primera columna sea la seleccionada por defecto.

Por ejemplo:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for(int i = 0; i != 30; ++i)
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Jose", "Ramirez", "0923611701");
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[0];
            dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);  
        }
    }
}
```

En ese ejemplo hacemos que la celda actual esté en la última fila. Con la propiedad [BeginEdit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit?view=netframework-4.8) logramos que la celda actual esté en modo de edicción.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda de verdad.